# Media Foundation cant get thumbnail

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I am trying to get a thumbnail from two mp3 files and save them to a file
For both of them i am able to get the thumbnail stream but for one of them i cant create a decoder with windows imaging componet and other works fine
I also tried gdi+ but the result was the same

Here is the file where i can get the decoder
[image: can get]
Thumbnail stream for the mp3
[image]
Here is the file where i cant get the decoder
[image: cant get]
Thumbnail stream for the mp3
[image]

```cpp
// How i get the thumbnail stream
comptr<IPropertyStore> properityStore;

hr = MFGetService(mediaSource.get(), MF_PROPERTY_HANDLER_SERVICE, IID_PPV_ARGS(properityStore.put()));

PROPVARIANT thumbnail;
PropVariantInit(&thumbnail);

IStream* thumbnailStream;
properityStore->GetValue(PKEY_ThumbnailStream, &thumbnail);

thumbnailStream = thumbnail.pStream;

PropVariantClear(&thumbnail);
```

Tried creating decoder in two ways

```cpp
// Hresult is WINCODEC_ERR_BADHEADER
comptr<IWICBitmapDecoder> decoder;
factory->CreateDecoder(GUID_ContainerFormatPng, nullptr, decoder.put());
hr = decoder->Initialize(thumbnailStream, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad);
```

```cpp
// Hresult is WINCODEC_ERR_COMPONENTNOTFOUND
comptr<IWICBitmapDecoder> decoder;
hr = factory->CreateDecoderFromStream(stream.get(), nullptr, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, decoder.put());
```

Is there any way to fix that or another api to use?

Comment: These are ID3 streams https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0 including an APIC frame, not images streams, you can use http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/ or https://taglib.org/ for example to read it, but manual extraction of included image should not be too much complicated by hand with the spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda figured it out
In the stream that i wasn't able to create decoder from there is a null character in the beginning removing it solved the issue
But why does media foundation gives the stream like that?

Here is the code for fixing the thumbnail header

```cpp
size_t FixHeader(BYTE* data)
{
    constexpr char pngHeader[] = "‰PNG";
    constexpr char jfifHeader[] = "ÿØÿà";

    size_t length = strlen((char*)data) + 1;
    BYTE* foundStrpng = (BYTE*)strstr((char*)data + length, pngHeader);
    BYTE* foundStrjfif = (BYTE*)strstr((char*)data + length, jfifHeader);

    if (foundStrjfif)
    {
        return foundStrjfif - data;
    }
    if (foundStrpng)
    {
        return foundStrpng - data;
    }

    return 0;
}

STATSTG stat;
thumbnailStream->Stat(&stat, NULL);

ULONG size = stat.cbSize.QuadPart;
BYTE* data = new BYTE[size];

ULONG read = -1;
thumbnailStream->Read(data, size, &read);

size_t offset = FixHeader(data);
size -= offset;

ULARGE_INTEGER newSize = { 0 };
newSize.QuadPart = size;
LARGE_INTEGER seekPos = { 0 };
seekPos.QuadPart = 0;
thumbnailStream->Seek(seekPos, STREAM_SEEK_SET, nullptr);
thumbnailStream->SetSize(newSize);
thumbnailStream->Seek(seekPos, STREAM_SEEK_SET, nullptr);
DWORD written = -1;
thumbnailStream->Write(data + offset, size, &written);
thumbnailStream->Seek(seekPos, STREAM_SEEK_SET, nullptr);
```